# Getting custom object of a Json with Async function

Tags: c#, json, async-await

I'm trying to use the HUE API, I was able to get the JSON with the list of the bulb but when i'm trying to make a custom object from it, its not working. No error and no exception, nothing is happening. Here's my attempt :

**LightsPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class LightsPage : Page
    {
        public LightsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listLights = Light.GetLightAsync();

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

**Light.cs**

```
 public class Light
    {
        private string name { get; set; }
        private string productname { get; set; }
        private string uniqueid { get; set; }
        private StateLight state { get; set; }
        public Light()
        {

        }
        public Light(string Name, string Productname, string Uniqueid, StateLight State)
        {
            name = Name;
            productname = Productname;
            uniqueid = Uniqueid;
            state = State;
        }

        static async public Task<List<Light>> GetLightAsync()
        {
            List<Light> lights = new List<Light>();

            Uri baseUri = new Uri($"http://{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IpBridge"]}");
            Uri apiUri = new Uri(baseUri, $"/api/{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"]}/lights");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUri);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            dynamic jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);

            foreach(var item in jsonResult)
            {
                Light light = new Light
                {
                    name = (string)item["name"],
                    productname = (string)item["productname"],
                    uniqueid = (string)item["uniqueid"],
                    state = new StateLight
                    {
                        on = (bool)item["state"]["on"],
                        bri = (int)item["state"]["bri"]
                    }
                };

                lights.Add(light);
            }


            return lights;

        }


    }
```

The JSON looks like this :

```
{"1":{"state":{"on":true,"bri":254,"alert":"select","mode":"homeautomation","reachable":true},
"swupdate":{"state":"noupdates","lastinstall":"2020-02-22T14:21:56"},
"type":"Dimmable light",
"name":"Salon blanc",
"modelid":"LWA001",
"manufacturername":"Signify Netherlands B.V.",
"productname":"Hue white lamp",
"capabilities":{"certified":true,"control":{"mindimlevel":5000,"maxlumen":800},
"streaming":{"renderer":false,"proxy":false}}, etc....
```

There is multiple bulb but you get the point.

In debug, when i'm reaching the construction of the objects Light in the loop, it stops there.

I'm fairly new to Task and Async so maybe it's coming from here but I don't know what to do...

Thx for your answers :)

Comment: Why don't you deserialise it to a concrete type instead of using dynamic and then all that manual assignment?

Comment: make Page_Loaded async ... and add await to GetLightAsync call

Comment: Anyway you aren't waiting for the async method to finish so the information just gets lost. You need to `await` it.

Comment: `var listLights` try change `var` to explicit type, you'll be surprized. And never use `var` if you not sure what type you'll get.

Comment: Tip: _[`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples) is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use._ Move it to `private static readonly` field outside of the method.

Comment: Deserealizer code may look like `lights = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Light>>(responseBody).Values.ToList()` without any additional results processing.

Comment: Thank you all for your response ! It work great now, still struggling with the explicit type to get all the information I need from the Json but i'll get there ! Thx again :)